# Stripe Payment Gateway: Issue with Upgrading Monthly to Annual Subscription - Order Summary Calculation

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, laravel-cashier

I'm developing a subscription payment system where users can upgrade from a monthly to an annual plan. The challenge I'm facing involves correctly calculating the order summary when a user decides to upgrade a few days after purchasing the monthly plan. I want to ensure the final amount accurately reflects the remaining days of the monthly plan and the full cost of the annual plan.

Example:-

- A user initially purchases a monthly plan and pays the full monthly amount.
- After 5 or 10 days, the user decides to upgrade to an annual plan.
- Before payment, I'm showing order summary to the user.
- In order summary, I need to show correct amount after adjustment of credit amount.

Is there any option on stripe payment gateway, where I send some information and Stripe provide me all the full order summary, before the payment something like

```
Monthly Plan (Remaining Days): $xxx
Annual Plan (12 months): $xxx
Total Credit from Monthly: $xxx
Total Amount for Upgrade: $xxx
```

I appreciate any insights or code examples or reference links that could help me implement this upgrade logic effectively.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Stripe Subscription supports [prorations](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations). In your case, you can update the Subscription to the annual price and set [proration to none](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior).

Imagine you've created the monthly Subscription using the following request:

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: customerId,
      items: [{
        price: monthlyPrice,
      }],
      payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
      payment_settings: { save_default_payment_method: 'on_subscription' },
      expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
});
```

After a while(couple of days), you want to upgrade the customer to an annual Subscription without creating a proration for the current month and charge the full next year:

```
 const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(subscriptionId, {
      items: [{
        price: annualPrice,
      }],
      proration_behavior: 'none'
 });
```

You can test this scenario using Stripe [Test clock](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks), where you can create a simulation and advance time.